# Domain restrictions for NMaximize

Tags: numerics

I am trying to solve a maximization problem, where my variable can only take a limited number of values. (Probably) the easiest example would be

```
dom = {0, 1/2}; NMaximize[{x^2, Element[x, dom]}, {x}]
```

While the `Element[x,dom]` syntax works just fine for `dom = Integers`, I keep getting error messages for any other domain. (edit: this seems to be because my chosen domain is invalid to use with ∈)

edit: I also tried the `MemberQ` syntax as stated below:

```
dom = {0, 1/2}; NMaximize[{x^2, MemberQ[dom, x]}, {x}]
```

This seems to be an acceptable constraint, but for some reason *Mathematica* seems unable to find a value that meets the constraint, as I get the following message:

> NMaximize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {False}.

Any other ideas?

edit: just to clarify. I need to restrict the variable(s) to a finite set of real numbers, hence I cannot use ">=/<=" constraints to get the job done. The above is just the simplest application I could think of.

Comment: Select `Element` and press F1 for an overview in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, rubenko! I gather that my chosen domain was invalid to use the \[Element] syntax. Another option I can think of is MemberQ, which unfortunately does not work either (I updated the post accordingly). So, I am out of ideas again...

Comment: `NMaximize[{x^2, 0 < x < .5, Element[x, Reals]}, {x}]` something like this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work, as I need to restrict the variable to a set of discrete options. (Obviously it would work for this example, but my real application has some 300 variables and >500 other constraints, so there is no way I could guarantee a border solution like above)

Answer (score 2):

For multiple domain range check than you can use something like this,

```
Map[(NMaximize[{x^2, #[[1]] < x < #[[2]], 
     Element[x, Reals]}, {x}]) &, {{.4, .5}, {.4, .6}}]
```

> {{0.25, {x -> 0.5}}, {0.36, {x -> 0.6}}}

You can put all your ranges as list.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element) accepts [`RegionQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionQ) objects as domains, you can create a custom domain with:

```
NMaximize[{x^2, {x} \[Element] Point[List /@ {0, 1/2}]}, x]
```

> {0.25, {x -> 0.5}}